# Google trends data for interest

Tags: causality, confounding

I was discussing about the popularity of some terms and used google trends to conclude in the decrease of their popularity.

[Here](http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=/m/01v0b8,%20/m/02s1yd,%20/m/01v0m4,%20/m/030fmv,%20/m/0l9nq&cmpt=q) is an exemple of the queries for some of the biggest french engineering schools. I concluded rapidly in a decreasing interest/popularity of these schools.

But giving another thought, I wondered if the decrease may have another explanation. Google trends give a relative number, proportional to the total number of queries. Is it possible that the population accessing google has so much evolved in these years that we can't conclude to a decrease in interest ?
I mean that the majority of queries should come from educated/wealthy people and researchers. So with the democratization of internet access the fraction of wealthy/educated people over total should have decreased. Thus explaining a decrease of the querries over total.

How can we show this effect ?
How can we remove this effect ?

Comment: You could incorporate the number of internet users in france (or Europe or w/e) by getting the data from wolframalpha: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=French+internet+usage+history

Comment: I think it refers to the total number of user, not on how a fraction of the total has evolved.